# Будет ли валидным код, где дочерний блок шире и выше родительского?

Tags: html, css

Будет ли валидным код, где дочерний блок шире и выше родительского?

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: -50px; left: -50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Валидным согласно чему? О каких стандартах вы сейчас говорите?

Comment: Вставляйте [**сюда**](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) и проверяйте :) . Или что Вы хотели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [официальному валидатору W3C](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) такой код будет валидным:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: 100px; left: 100px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: -50px; left: -50px;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.